# Multi-Command Git Alias not working

Tags: git, alias

I am trying to set up a git alias to essentially deal with the annoying steps before I submit code.

I want the alias to do a fetch on origin/develop, merge origin/develop into my current branch, and then push my current branch"

What I have is:

```
git config --global alias.latestPush "fetch origin/develop; git merge origin/develop && git push
```

Every time I try to setup and run this alias, I get some error or another.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: Add `!git ` before `fetch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing this bit from the [`git-config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it will be
>   treated as a shell command.

Without the `!`, the alias arguments are passed as arguments to the `git` command (which doesn't know how to handle multiple commands separated by `;`).